# C Program crashing when integer is modified

Tags: c

I'm attempting to get the content-length from an http header before receiving the data using sockets. No I cannot use libcurl.

Whatever I do causes the program to crash. This is running on a Wii as homebrew,  that might be the cause. I have no idea what causes this.

This code is not compilable, it's just to give insight. 'ptr' is the buffer which contains the http header.

```c
int bytes_received;

ptr=strstr(ptr,"Content-Length: ");
ptr+=16;
if(ptr){
    bytes_received = atoi(strtok(ptr, "\r\n"));
}else{
    bytes_received=-1; //unknown size
}

int contentLength = bytes_received;

FILE* fp;
fp = fopen("tex.jpg", "wb");

int n;
while(contentLength > 1){
    n = recv(sockfd, response, 1024,0);
    if(n==-1){
        return;
    }
    fwrite(response,sizeof(char),n,fp);

    contentLength-=n; //This line is causing the crash
}

fclose(fp);
```

When executing this using the Wii, I get the "Exception occurred" screen with the code dump leading to the line which I have marked. I have no idea what's causing this issue. Please help.

Comment: What is the definition of `response`?

Comment: You *must* check `if(ptr)` **before** `ptr+=16;`, not after. Also, `atoi(strtok(ptr, "\r\n"));` begs perfectly expected input.

Comment: It's all very well saying the code is for "insight", but when you set `bytes_received=-1` and blithely continue, we have to ask for the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the problem.

Comment: Welcome! As a new user you might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "When executing this" Impossible, it does not even compile. Please provide an MRE.

Comment: The code should ALWAYS check the value of fopen calls. The code will crash  if fp is NULL. Also, consider changing the write loop to contentLength>0.